# ionic 3 google maps Cannot read property 'Autocomplete' of undefined

Tags: google-maps, ionic-framework, autocomplete, ionic3

Working on ionic 3 project i could use google maps so far, i want to use google places autocomplete , i used this answer [Answer](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/google-maps-typescript-error-cannot-find-name-google-discussion/49990/20) to solve problem 'cannot find name  google' when i type `let input = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(element);`

and it worked and now the app run, but now i get new error

'ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'Autocomplete' of undefined'

what should i do?

> EDIT (1)

when i use `console.log(google.maps);` i get result, but when i use `console.log(google.maps.places);` i get undefined.

but when i click on `places`in VSCode it show me that it exist

```
    export module places {
        export class Autocomplete extends MVCObject {
            constructor(inputField: HTMLInputElement, opts?: AutocompleteOptions);
            getBounds(): LatLngBounds;
            getPlace(): PlaceResult;
            setBounds(bounds: LatLngBounds|LatLngBoundsLiteral): void;
            setComponentRestrictions(restrictions: ComponentRestrictions): void;
            setTypes(types: string[]): void;
        }
etc etc
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to include the following line of code in your index.html

Note: if you have an existing google maps javascript there, you would need to replace it with this

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&libraries=places&key=YOUR_KEY"></script>
```

where : YOUR_KEY is your developer's key